# Call a function on popup's close icon click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I use OSM maps with [Leaflet JS](https://leafletjs.com). On that map I create popups like this:

```
popup.setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(info).openOn(map);
```

Is there a way to call another function but only when the popup is closed by clicking the close button in the upper right corner?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be resolved like this, for example:

```js
// config map
let config = {
  minZoom: 7,
  maxZoom: 18,
};
// magnification with which the map will start
const zoom = 18;
// co-ordinates
const lat = 52.22977;
const lng = 21.01178;

// calling map
const map = L.map("map", config).setView([lat, lng], zoom);

// Used to load and display tile layers on the map
// Most tile servers require attribution, which you can set under `Layer`
L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

// one marker
L.marker([52.22983, 21.011728]).addTo(map).bindPopup("Center Warsaw");

function onMapClick(e) {
  const closeButton = e.popup._closeButton;
  closeButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    alert("ok");
  });

  map.off("popupclose");
}

map.on("popupclose", onMapClick);
```

```css
*,
:after,
:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
html,
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is way, by Inspecting HTML you can get the class name of the close button that appearng here and you can write following code to do what you want.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-popup-close-button')[0].onclick = () => {
    //alert("test");
    //write code...
}
```

In the case of their quick start example here : https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/ it was `leaflet-popup-close-button` Ofcouse the library using same classes.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, great idea, not the way I was going. Unfortunately, if the popup is added dynamically I get an error message that it is undefined...

Comment: @santa You can wait untill dom is fully loaded using DOMLoaded event Look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event